# Get specific css attribute from style property

Tags: jquery, asp.net

I have this asp.net label. As it is a server control and I want to store some custom information, I have stored it in css style. The idea is browser won't understand this attribute so it will just ignore whereas if I put it directly as some inbuilt property it will throw compile time error. This is my code:

```
<asp:Label runat="server" id="sample" style="fakeStyle:someValue" />
```

How do I get the value of `fakeStyle` using Jquery?

Comment: y don u try doing this using hidden fields!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't do that. Use custom attribute instead:

```
<asp:Label runat="server" id="sample" fake_attribute="somevalue" />
```

Then read it like this:

```
var myVal = $("#<%=sample.ClientID%>").attr("fake_attribute");
```

For the record, you *can* read CSS value with such code:

```
var myVal = $("#<%=sample.ClientID%>").css("fakeStyle");
```

But like I said, having invalid CSS is not a good idea.

Comment: This works. Wow. Nice! Didn't expect this to work so didn't even try. I thought it would throw compile time or runtime error ;)

Comment: ASP.NET is not totally dumb.. it will just throw any non reserved attributes (e.g. custom attributes) out to the browser as-is without any parsing, adding them to the generated tag. :)

Answer (score 2):

Please don't do that. It is very horrible.

You can use data attributes instead. jQuery let's you use HTM5ish data attributes which work on most browsers.

```
<asp:Label runat="server" id="sample" data-something="my data" />

jQuery:

alert($("#sample").data("something"));
```

http://api.jquery.com/data/

Comment: +1 for elegant solution, but we still have some time (year?) before HTML5 is supported by 95% of the active browsers around the world.

Comment: @Shadow: That is true. Perhaps that is why only I have marked your answer as valid. But +1  to karim79

Comment: @Shadow Wizard - I agree, but since both solutions are about the same amount of effort to implement, wouldn't you prefer one which is already future-proof?

Comment: I won't have code that fails for about 30% of my visitors. It's possible to check and have "fallback" in case the browser does not support this, but this will already make the code complicated. As I don't think custom attributes will be deprecated, I can say my code is also future proof, just not very elegant. :)

Comment: @Shadow Wizard - The point is, the data attributes will not fail for 30% of people because jQuery makes 'em work, even in older browsers. When I said "future proof" what I actually meant was you won't need to change them to HTML5 attributes in the future. The solution I posted *does* rely on jQuery. I'm not saying this is better than your solution, I just don't think you're seeing the point I'm trying to make. (or, I'm completely wrong and should keep quiet :)